# Implementing single log4net config file across multiple projects

Tags: log4net-configuration

I'm trying to use a solution that I've put together from a few other answers on here.  Basically I'm trying to use one log4net config file for a solution that has multiple projects.

Here is my config file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
  <log4net>
    <appender name="FileMonitorAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
      <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="C:\Documents and Settings\user1\My Documents\My Box Files\FOBS\logs\Box File Monitor %date{MM.dd.yyyy'_'hh.mm.ss''}.txt" />
      <appendToFile value="true"/>
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <header value="[START: Box File Monitor Run %date]%newline" type="log4net.Util.PatternString" />
        <conversionPattern value="%date{HH:mm:ss} - %-5level- %message%newline" />
        <footer value="[END: Box File Monitor Run]" />
      </layout>
    </appender>

    <root>
      <level value="ALL"/>
      <appender-ref ref="FileMonitorAppender" />
    </root>
  </log4net>
```

and here is where I'm calling the logger in code:

```cs
private static readonly ILog _log = LogManager.GetLogger("Duke.Mobile.FileMonitorAutomation.FileMonitor");
```

and I also have this in the calling assembly which is supposed to configure the logger:

```cs
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "Log4Net.config", Watch = true)]
```

I have the log4net.config file in a solution folder and then have it added to the calling assembly as a linked file.  When the app runs, it never hits the configuration.  I've seen a couple of similar problems but it's never set up exactly this way, hoping someone can help.

Comment: May be this link will help you..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17874999/log4net-for-windows-service/17875059#17875059

Comment: I realized that this is a little more involved than I thought. I have a project that is implementing log4Net in the solution, as described above, and then a setup a deployment project where it appears it is actually looking for the file to do the configuration. Since I'm using a linked file, I guess I need to figure out how to reference it from the S&D project.  The main objective here is to have a single configuration file that can be read from all of the separate projects.

Comment: Figured out my problem.  When using a linked config file for log4net, within a Windows service project, the config file's build action needs to be set to 'Content' in the file's properties.  From there, in the deployment project, the file needs to be included in the project output.

Comment: Great I think the question will help someone in future :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using a linked config file for log4net, within a Windows service project, the config file's build action needs to be set to 'Content' in the file's properties. From there, in the deployment project, the file needs to be included in the project output